# How to display ACTIVE products only?

Tags: function, search

**What should be the right code for me to be able to search for a product that is only ACTVE, i do have a product_status column in my database. Thanks in advance!**

```
Public Sub prodsearch()

        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
            Label3.Hide()
        Else
            Label3.Show()
        End If

        con.Open()

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter _
        ("Select * FROM tbl_products where prod_code like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_name like '%" _
         & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_price like '%" _
         & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_brand like '%" _
         & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_manufacturer like '%" _
         & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_remarks like '%" _
         & TextBox1.Text & "%'", con)

            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        End Using

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        con.Close()


Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

prodsearch()

End Sub
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIMmt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'
Public Sub prodsearch2()

```
    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        Label3.Hide()
    Else
        Label3.Show()
    End If

    con.Open()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter _
    ("Select * FROM tbl_products WHERE prod_status='ACTIVE' and prod_code like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_status='ACTIVE' and prod_name like '%" & TextBox1.Text _
         & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_status='ACTIVE' and prod_price like '%" _
         & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_status='ACTIVE' and prod_brand like '%" _
        & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_status='ACTIVE' and prod_manufacturer like '%" _
        & TextBox1.Text & "%' or prod_status='ACTIVE' and prod_remarks like '%" _
           & TextBox1.Text & "%'", con)

        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    con.Close()

    Label2.Text = "No of results found: " & DataGridView1.RowCount

    If DataGridView1.RowCount = 0 Then
        Button1.Enabled = False
    Else
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        Label2.Hide()
    Else
        Label2.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

'